# UILabel blinking effect

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode6

I am using UIButton with blinking effect. I have used this code for blinking effect on UIButton

```
UIButton *random = (UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:i+20];
random.alpha = 0;
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 delay:0.2 options:UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse animations:^{
         random.alpha = 1;
        } completion:nil];
```

This code will blink the UIButton but I want to stop this blinking effect after 3 time blinks I don't know how to stop this blinking effect.
So if anybody knows solution please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `[UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:3]` within your animation block. You shouldn't use `UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat` flag since it makes your `repeatCount` indefinite.

I guess if Apple did not provide `repeatCount` for `UIView` animations as they provide it for `CABasicAnimation`, it would be a big step backwards.

Answer (score 6):

Use `CABasicAnimation` instead of UIView Animation

```
UIButton *random = (UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:i+20];
random.alpha = 0;

CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
[animation setFromValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0]];
[animation setToValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0]];
[animation setDuration:0.2f];
[animation setRepeatCount:3];
[animation setAutoreverses:YES];
[animation setRemovedOnCompletion:NO];
[random.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"animation"];
```